# Batch insert in MariaDB with on duplicate key update

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, mariadb

I have the following table cl:

```
id - int(10) primary key
contact - int(10)
list - int(10)
```

With a unique index on contact and list. When I run concurrently the following query in batch by 100 records:

```
INSERT INTO cl(list, contact) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cl.id = cl.id
```

Under high pressure it fails in about 20% with the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cl.id = cl.id' at line 1
```

80% of the queries runs just fine. When I rerun failed queries with the same parameters, again 20% fail.

Why some of the queries fail and then produce no errors when executed for the second time?

Comment: I think that your sql doesn't make sense(not in a rude way)....I think that you should do something like, for example, if you want to update the list then: `INSERT INTO cl(list, contact) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE list = ?`...or if you want to update contact, then you should try: `INSERT INTO cl(list, contact) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE contact = ?`...or if you want to update both: `INSERT INTO cl(list, contact) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE list = ?,contact = ?`....

Comment: The idea is do not change already available records in the table. In any case, the failure is not due to the fact that a duplicate is there: there are no records with a same key in the table when the query is run.

Comment: But I still don't understand...`on key duplicate update` is mainly used when you are passing the id as parameter also, like: `INSERT INTO cl(id,list, contact) VALUES (?,?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cl.id = cl.id`...you are not passing the id, and  if the id is also autoincrement, then you should never going to reach the on dup key update part.....

Comment: On duplicate reached when unique combination of list and contact is hit due to unique index on contact and list.

Comment: Mmmmm....still unclear....btw on the documentation this phrase looks interesting: `It is not recommended to use this statement on tables with more than one unique index.`....

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can point out that it is missing a `UNIQUE` key on `list` and/or `contact`.

Comment: If there were to be `UNIQUE(list, contact)` why have `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing query to

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO cl(list, contact) VALUES (?, ?)
```

solved the issue. Though it is unclear why mysql was throwing java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException instead of something more unambiguous.